# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre ViewBag, ViewData?

Tags: asp.net, mvc

Sabemos que  `ViewData` o `ViewBag` son utilizados para pasar información del controlador a la vista.

¿Existe alguna diferencia entre ambos?  Por ejemplo, en cuanto al rendimiento y si es recomendable el uso de uno en particular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ViewBag` es simplemente un wrapper sobre `ViewData`. La diferencia es que mientras que `ViewData` es de tipo `ViewDataDictionary` (que implementa un `IDictionary<string, object>`, `ViewBag` es de tipo `dynamic` lo que simplifica el código ligeramente.

Ejemplo:

```
ViewData["Persona"] = new Persona("Alice");

// o

ViewBag.Persona = new Persona("Alice");
```

En cuando a diferencia en rendimiento debería ser despreciable, preocúpate mejor por otros lugares que pueden realmente ser un cuello de botella como por ejemplo acceso a base de datos

En cuanto a cual es mejor, pues la sintaxis de `dynamic` es ligeramente mas corta, pero es cuestión de gustos. Ten en cuenta que ninguna de las dos opciones son strongly typed lo cual puede conllevar a tener errores en tiempo de ejecución si tipeas mal el key en este caso `Persona` . Lo ideal en realidad es pasar toda la información entre el controller y la vista mediante un `Model`

Answer (score 4):

Básicamente, las diferencias consisten en lo siguiente:

## `ViewData`

- `ViewData` es un objeto de diccionario fuertemente tipado en el que se introducen los datos a través de la conocida sintaxis "`key`/`value`".
- `ViewData` deriva de la clase `ViewDataDictionary`.
- Uso y asignación al objetos: `ViewData["Dato"] = 1`
- Lectura del objeto en la vista: `@ViewData["Dato"]`

## `ViewBag`

- El objeto `ViewBag` es un objeto de tipo dinámico que le permite crear propiedades *al vuelo*.
- Uso y asignación al objetos `ViewBag.Dato = 1`
- Lectura del objeto en la vista: `@ViewBag.Dato`

En general, el uso de uno o de otro (considero) que dependerá de la forma que más te acomodes, ambos te funcionan para el paso de información del controlador a la vista, a menos que desees acarrear esa información durante más de una petición, entonces en ese caso considera usar el diccionario de datos [`TempData`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.tempdatadictionary(v=vs.118).aspx) en conjunto con su método [`Keep()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.tempdatadictionary.keep(v=vs.118).aspx).

Referencias a la documentación oficial:

- [`ViewData`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.viewpage.viewdata(v=vs.118).aspx)
- [`ViewBag`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.viewbag(v=vs.118).aspx)
- [`TempData`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.tempdatadictionary(v=vs.118).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

En realidad no dejan de ser dos caras de la misma moneda.

La principal diferencia es que mientras ViewData es un diccionario de objetos en el que puedes acceder a elementos de tipo Object a través de una cadena, ViewBag es un objeto dinámico en el que puedes acceder a elementos a través de propiedades creadas de forma dinámica y que pueden tener un tipo de datos definido.

A la hora de la verdad MVC almacena la información en el mismo contenedor de forma que un valor definido en el controlador como `ViewData["dato1"] = xxxxx` puede ser accedido desde la vista como `ViewBag.dato1` y viceversa.

Answer (score 2):

Ambos tienen el mismo objetivo pasar datos desde el controlador a la vista.

El ViewData es de tipo Object y hay que hacer cast en la vista para utilizarlo, mientras que el ViewBag se genera dinámicamente con el tipo de dato asignado.

ViewData: Requiere casting de tipo para datos de tipos complejos y comprobar los valores nulos para evitar errores.

ViewBag: No requiere casting de tipo para tipo de datos complejos.

Controlador:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
   public ActionResult Index()
   {
      var emp = new Empleado
      {
        IdEmpleado=101,
        Nombre = "Pedro",
        Salario = 3500,
        Direccion = "Chiapas"
      };

      ViewData["emp"] = emp;
      ViewBag.Empleado = emp;

      return View(); 
   }
}
```

Vista:

```
@model MyProject.Models.Empleado;
 @{ 
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"; 
    ViewBag.Title = "Bienvenido";
    var viewDataEmpleado = ViewData["emp"] as Empleado; //se hace el casting
  }

 <h2>Bienvenido</h2>
 Mejor empleado del año!
 <h4>@ViewBag.Empleado.Nombre</h4>
 <h3>@viewDataEmpleado.Nombre</h3>
```

Answer (score 2):

primero que todo gracias por sus repsuestas. Me han aclarao la duda, no obstante quisiera publicar otra respuesta con el fin de contribuir a esclarecer este tema, aunque creo que ya lo han cubierto todo bastante bien.

Técnicamente, todos los datos se pasan de los controladores a las vistas a través de un ViewDataDictionary (una clase de diccionario especializada) llamada ViewData. Puede establecer y leer valores en el diccionario ViewData utilizando la sintaxis del diccionario estándar de la siguiente manera:

```
ViewData["CurrentTime"] = DateTime.Now;
```

Aunque esto continúa estando disponible, ASP.NET MVC 3 aprovechó la palabra clave dynamic de C # 4 para permitir una sintaxis más simple. ViewBag es un contenedor dinámico alrededor de ViewData. Le permite establecer los valores como sigue:

```
ViewBag.CurrentTime = DateTime.Now;
```

Así, ViewBag.CurrentTime es equivalente a ViewData["CurrentTime"].
Generalmente, la mayoría del código actual que encontrarás usa ViewBag en vez de ViewData 
en su mayor parte. Usted no tiene una verdadera ventaja técnica al elegir una sintaxis sobre la otra. ViewBag es simplemente atajo de sintaxis que algunas personas prefieren sobre la sintaxis del diccionario. Simplemente se ve mejor.

Aunque es posible que no tenga una ventaja técnica para elegir un formato sobre 
el otro, usted debe ser consciente de algunas diferencias importantes entre las dos
Sintaxis
Una diferencia obvia es que ViewBag funciona sólo cuando la clave a la que está accediendo
Es un identificador de C # válido. Por ejemplo, si coloca un valor en ViewData ["Key
Con Espacios "], no puede acceder a ese valor con ViewBag porque el código
No se compilará.
Otra cuestión clave a considerar es que no se pueden transmitir valores dinámicos como parámetros a los métodos de extensión. El compilador C # debe conocer el tipo real de cada parámetro en tiempo de compilación para elegir el método de extensión correcto.
Si cualquier parámetro es dinámico, la compilación fallará. Por ejemplo, este código
Siempre fallan: @ Html.TextBox ("nombre", ViewBag.Name). Para evitar esto,
Use ViewData ["Name"] o moldee el valor a un tipo específico: (string) ViewBag.Name.

ViewDataDictionary es una clase especializada de diccionario, no solo un Dictionary genérico
.Una razón para esto es que tiene una propiedad de modelo adicional que permite un
Objeto de modelo específico que debe estar disponible para la vista. Porque sólo puede tener un objeto modelo en
ViewData, usar esto para pasar una clase específica a la vista es conveniente. Esto le permite a su vista especificar la clase que espera el objeto del modelo deseado, lo que significa que puede aprovechar fuertemente tipado.

Esto es traducido de un libro el cual considero de los mejores que he leido **Professional ASP.Net MVC5**